# Нулевые размеры GridPane при добавлении на экран

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Пишу мини-игру на JavaFX, с целью ознакомления с данной технологией, и столкнулся с необычной проблемой. При добавлении на корневую панель, в качестве которой выступает `StackPane`, игрового поля (`GridPane`), оно (игровое поле) на экране отображается как положено, однако методы `getWidth()` и `getHeight()` возвращают `0.0`. Из-за этого на поле невозможно добавить игровые объекты и вообще взаимодействовать с ним. Само поле добавляю так

```
root.getChildren().add(fightScreen);
```

Где  `root`-это `StackPane`, `fightScreen`-это `GridPane`.

В игре присутствуют и другие `GridPane`, с ними проблем не возникает. Проблема только с данной панелью.

Всё создавал с помощью SceneBuilder, но на всякий случай приведу код для данной панели

```
<GridPane focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity"
          minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" styleClass="grid-pane" stylesheets="@csss/FightScreen.css"
          vgap="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.view.FightScreenController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="555.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="111.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="229.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="35.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="229.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="60.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="483.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="344.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="304.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="190.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="303.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="59.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Hero" textFill="#ba1818">
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label text="Enemy" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT">
         <padding>
            <Insets right="20.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
         <font>
            <Font name="Britannic Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <HBox fx:id="hero" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="5.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <HBox fx:id="enemy" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="5.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="190.0" prefWidth="373.0" styleClass="anchor-pane-2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="anchor-pane-1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Буду благодарен, если подскажете, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил сам. Размеры становятся нормальными после того, как начинает работать `Animation Timer`